# Date format issue in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet which has a column logDate and the values in the column are like below

1. '03/08/2017
2. 03/08/2017

When I import this data to MySQL table using google apps script

'03/08/2017 this date gets stored as 03/08/2017

03/08/2017 this date gets stored as Wed Mar 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (EST)

So I tried to change the logDate column to a consistent date format using code below.

```
  var ldcol = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:A");
  ldcol.setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

This formatted logDate column data to below

1. 03/08/2017
2. 03/08/2017

and in the table logDate column data looks like this "Wed Mar 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (EST)".

[image: GS1]
[image: GS2]

Comment: So, in the spreadsheet there are two date values in every cell?  One with a single quote in front of it?  What is the problem?  What do you want for an end result?  I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: Each cell has 1 value. The date that starts with an apostrophe gets stored as 03/08/2017 in the table and the one without an apostrophe is stored as Wed Mar 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (EST). I am trying to make the date values in the column consistent using the setNumberFormat and that makes the date value stored as this Wed Mar 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (EST). My question is how do I make the date values in this column consistent and store them as date in MM/dd/yyyy format?

Answer (score 0):

The first one (with single quote) is a string, the other one is a date value.
Dates in JavaScript are always represented in their complete form, for example "Wed Mar 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (EST)".

If you want to use both objects the same way you can either convert both to date objects or both to strings.

From what you say, I guess you prefer to use the shorter string version so you can use a Google special method called `formatDate`, it goes like this :

```
var ldcol = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:A").getValues();//this returns an array of arrays with all col values
var ldcolTest = ldcol[0][0]; // pick first value to test it, implement a loop to check all values
var formatedDate = Utilities.formatDate(ldcolTest, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
Logger.log("formatedDate = "+formatedDate);
```

Comment: Hi Serge insas, I am already using the formatDate method. The problem I have is even though I change the cell value as text                          `var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:A");
  value.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');`                                                  it works fine in some cases and sometimes not. I have updated my original post with date I see in my sheets.

Comment: spreadsheets try to be smart and detect a lot of things... in this case it seems that forcing a string format with formatNumber is not sufficient to keep from interpreting the value as a date. Have you tried to add a preceding comma in the second value , something like `var formatedDate = "'"+Utilities.formatDate(ldcolTest, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");`